# does every git commit have to be error free and perfect?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a small side project (hobby project, not for business purpose) and collaborate with another developer.

we are using Git to manage. However, my teammate seems to be quite picky to every commit.
He said that projects like Chrome, they have a very strict commit format and he wants me to follow that way. But I feel for a small two-man project, it would be quite good if we can make this flexible that I can commit my codes and latter to fix any bugs.
Sometimes, I found he even rebased the code that the code can keep in one line( commit graph).

Sometimes, I forgot to open a feature branch and worked on the master branch, then I am in the middle of something, but I've being told I can't commit my unfinished code so that I couldn't commit it until I finish it. ( that's annoying consider the hard drive may die, I will lose my code)

I am just wondering, how important it is to make every commit with really high standard and error free? Do all the projects regardless it's size need to be managed like that?

Comment: Take a look at this -> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/211608/is-it-ever-ok-to-commit-non-working-code

Comment: and this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119784/is-it-good-idea-to-require-to-commit-only-working-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your colleague is right. Keeping your master branch stable is a really good practice. It makes sure your colleagues can always start from master and have something working. And a linear history is really helpful to figure out why things happened, and which change introduced a bug. So rebasing a feature branch before merging it to master is a good thing.

Put whatever you want in feature branches and learn git: you can do

```
git checkout -b someFeature
```

from master, even if you already have modifications, then commit and push that branch, without modifying master.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to keep every *public* commit in the master branch perfect. No unfinished work and things like that over there.

With your private branches, you can do whatever you want. Just make sure you fix up the commit before merging it back into master.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is just a place where you can store your code, so yes it possible to commit and push code with bugs. However doing so its not a good practice, especially if you are working with a partner. This can cause confusion and problems for him or her since they might not know about the problem.

When I work with other people on GitHub, we use different branches. The "Master" or "Production" branch should have the latest working version of your project. Then under "Master" you can create another branch called "Develop" where you and your partners can make pull request from their personal branches. Once you have another good version of your project you can merge it with your Master branch.
By following this process and with enough communication, your partner and you should have a more enjoyable experience!